# How to Check if a number is of 4 digits in C?

Tags: c

How to Check if a number is of 4 digits in C?
My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int check4(int number)
{
if ((number % 10) && !(number / 10000) && (number / 1000) && (number / 100) && (number / 10))
         printf(" 4 Numbers");


}

}
```

?

Comment: What can you say about the smallest 4 digit number and the largest 4 digit number? Does that help you solve your problem?

Comment: Something like `log(number) + 1 == 4`

Comment: `number >= 1000 && number <= 9999` ?

Comment: `if(number >= 1000 && number <10000) ....`

Comment: @Maroun yes .... complex math float functions are really needed here

Comment: @Maroun do you know why you should not use float functions when deal with integers? Do you know how long this function executes on 8 bits uC for example. It is a very good example of bad programming :0

Comment: @P__J__ there you go... this explanation is better than "yeah, complex functions are really needed here" comment, and it might help others avoid such approach :)

Comment: Try case 0000. Use regex.

Comment: @Maroun did you mean `log10()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not familiar with C, I suggested a pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

> All 4 digit numbers must be greater than or equal to 1,000 and less than or equal to 9,999.
>   Any number satisfying this condition will definitely consist of 4 digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num = 4500;

    if (num >= 1000 && num <= 9999) {
        printf("It is a 4 digit number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
if (number >= 1000  &&  number  <= 9999)
```

Comment: Can you Give me Full Code?

Comment: @MuathHasan it is full code. Nothing else is needed